# `pip download` a mixture of wheels and source code for cross platform

Tags: python, pip, pytorch-lightning

I've been using `pip download` to download wheels on **Windows** and moving them to **Linux** system for installation, because the Linux system has no access to Internet. However, when I tried to download `lightning` by:

```
pip download lightning --python-version 310 --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: -d "D:\path_to_download"
```

It would start to download `lightning` and several dependencies including `numpy`, `torch`, etc. Then I got the following error, since the package [`fire`](https://pypi.org/project/fire/) does not have any wheel available:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fire (from lightning-utilities) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for fire
```

After this error, all the downloaded packages were just discarded.

**So my questions are**:

- Is there a way to `pip download` packages with a mixture of wheels and source code? Note that under **cross-platform** situation (`--platform manylinux2014_x86_64`), option `--prefer-binary` is not available.

```
ERROR: When restricting platform and interpreter constraints using --python-version, --platform, --abi, or --implementation, either --no-deps must be set, or --only-binary=:all: must be set and --no-binary must not be set (or must be set to :none:).
```

- Or, is there a way to ignore the error and save all the available wheels? In that case, I can download `fire` manually.

Comment: No to both question. Cross-platform downloading works pretty bad. Use WSL2, a VM or a container with the target Linux and Python version, download there and move to the offline host.

Comment: @phd Figured as much. Unfortunately, it's not an option for me, because it's strictly prohibited to install any additional OS on devices that has Internet access in our company. Guess I need to figure out a way somehow. Thanks for the advice though :)

Comment: Does this help pip install fire?